# Intellij on linux: Android project creation fails with error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have `Intellij Ultimate` installed on `Ubuntu 16.04`, `JDK` is installed with `openjdk 8` and `android-sdk` is manually installed from the official android website, i have set up `Intellij Ultimate` to make use of this `android-sdk` in the settings so i could start working with android applications.

In the main menu where recent projects are listed i select to create a new project, the project type is android of course, but after selecting all the options for the new project it returns to the main menu and does nothing, on the error log it shows the following:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.GradleSyncStats$Builder.setEmbeddedRepoEnabled(Z)Lcom/google/wireless/android/sdk/stats/GradleSyncStats$Builder;
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.generateSyncEvent(GradleSyncState.java:483)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncStarted(GradleSyncState.java:212)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncStarted(GradleSyncState.java:181)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:225)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$0(GradleSyncInvoker.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.openOrImportProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:210)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.importProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:168)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.project.NewProjectModel$ProjectTemplateRenderer.performGradleImport(NewProjectModel.java:345)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:781)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:722)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

i have tried by removing the android sdk folder and let `Intellij Ultimate` to handle the installation by itself, create a new project again but the error happens the same.. I have checked if `Intellij Ultimate` does create the project folder (which it does) but after importing it and check on the main layout it stays on `Waiting for build to finish...` and another error happens:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$Invoker.addNavigationFiles(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/android/manifmerger/ManifestMerger2$Invoker;
    at com.android.tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo.getMergedManifest(ManifestInfo.java:99)
    at com.android.tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo$ManifestFile.parseManifest(ManifestInfo.java:315)
    at com.android.tools.idea.model.ManifestInfo$ManifestFile.refresh(ManifestInfo.java:380)
    at com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.syncWithReadPermission(MergedManifest.java:386)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:925)
    at com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.sync(MergedManifest.java:365)
    at com.android.tools.idea.model.MergedManifest.getPackage(MergedManifest.java:152)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.PackageClassConverter.getManifestPackage(PackageClassConverter.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.PackageClassConverter.createReferences(PackageClassConverter.java:142)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GenericValueReferenceProvider.a(GenericValueReferenceProvider.java:124)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GenericValueReferenceProvider.a(GenericValueReferenceProvider.java:115)
    at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.GenericValueReferenceProvider.getReferencesByElement(GenericValueReferenceProvider.java:75)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.getReferences(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:135)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.mapNotEmptyReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.doGetReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistryImpl.java:102)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:50)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.resolve.reference.ReferenceProvidersRegistry.getReferencesFromProviders(ReferenceProvidersRegistry.java:44)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeValueImpl.getReferences(XmlAttributeValueImpl.java:110)
    at com.intellij.xml.util.XmlRefCountHolder$IdGatheringRecursiveVisitor.visitXmlAttributeValue(XmlRefCountHolder.java:249)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeValueImpl.accept(XmlAttributeValueImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.visit(PsiWalkingState.java:70)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.visit(PsiWalkingState.java:27)
    at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.walkChildren(WalkingState.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.elementStarted(WalkingState.java:52)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.elementStarted(PsiWalkingState.java:79)
    at com.intellij.psi.XmlRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.visitElement(XmlRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.java:38)
    at com.intellij.xml.util.XmlRefCountHolder$IdGatheringRecursiveVisitor.visitElement(XmlRefCountHolder.java:177)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiElementVisitor.visitFile(PsiElementVisitor.java:34)
    at com.intellij.psi.XmlRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.visitFile(XmlRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.java:56)
    at com.intellij.psi.XmlElementVisitor.visitXmlFile(XmlElementVisitor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl.accept(XmlFileImpl.java:71)
    at com.intellij.xml.util.XmlRefCountHolder$1.lambda$compute$0(XmlRefCountHolder.java:61)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
    at com.intellij.xml.util.XmlRefCountHolder.getRefCountHolder(XmlRefCountHolder.java:79)
    at com.intellij.xml.util.XmlDuplicatedIdInspection$1.visitXmlAttributeValue(XmlDuplicatedIdInspection.java:53)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeValueImpl.accept(XmlAttributeValueImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.acceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:75)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionEngine.createVisitorAndAcceptElements(InspectionEngine.java:63)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.runToolOnElements(LocalInspectionsPass.java:276)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.lambda$visitPriorityElementsAndInit$3(LocalInspectionsPass.java:244)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.execAndForkSubTasks(ApplierCompleter.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1156)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$wrapInReadActionAndIndicator$1(ApplierCompleter.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.wrapInReadActionAndIndicator(ApplierCompleter.java:116)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.lambda$compute$0(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:222)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.ApplierCompleter.compute(ApplierCompleter.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecCC(ForkJoinPool.java:1190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.helpComplete(ForkJoinPool.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitJoin(ForkJoinPool.java:2045)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:390)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke(ForkJoinPool.java:2616)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncherImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncher.invokeConcurrentlyUnderProgress(JobLauncher.java:56)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.visitPriorityElementsAndInit(LocalInspectionsPass.java:247)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.inspect(LocalInspectionsPass.java:218)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LocalInspectionsPass.collectInformationWithProgress(LocalInspectionsPass.java:121)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(ProgressableTextEditorHighlightingPass.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:69)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:423)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1161)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:416)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:415)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:391)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:222)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:389)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

I have no idea on how to fix this.. i've researched on the internet but no answers found and i would like to see if this could be fixed before jumping into downloading `Android Studio` which i believe is better to make `Intellij Ultimate` work on this since `Android Studio` is actually `Intellij`

Comment: I am just curious. Are you seeing any added value for **Intellij IDE** over **Android Studio** for Android Projects?

Comment: @shizhen one thing I've found is that if you want to access a database used by your Android app inside your emulator then IntelliJ can help you whereas Android Studio cannot

Comment: As for the original question: I've never seen this particular error, but a NoSuchMethodError generally means you have a version incompatibility, in this case probably between IntelliJ and the Android SDK. Which versions are you using?

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I am not sure about the database issues you are talking about. What I know is no matter it is a device or emulator, Android Studio has no problems with accessing a database of a particular Android app. Maybe you have ever encountered some problems which I don't know.

Comment: For me, I will just download the latest Android Studio for Android projects instead of Intellij unless you say that you are trying something different on purpose.

Comment: @Shizhen under Tool Windows there's a Database option in IntelliJ that is absent in Android Studio (I just compared Android Studio 3.1.3 to IntelliJ 2018.2.1). We use that to look at the app database in the Genymotion emulator

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I am using the latest on both intellij and android-sdk..

Comment: @shizhen i would like to keep intellij ultimate as my main IDE for most of the languages i work on, but if i cannot fix this problem then sadly i will have to download android studio and use it separatedly

Comment: I would like to recommend Android studio for Android project although there is someone saying that IntelliJ has some advantages over android studios